# Parsing xml nodes - removing empty nodes

Tags: java

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version ='1.0'?>
<cjischarges>    
<cjischarge>
  <cjisid>1</cjisid>
  <chargeid>1</chargeid>
  <cjiscode>10000</cjiscode>
  <class></class>
  <cjisclass>1 0000</cjisclass>
  <describe35>VESSEL-CONCEAL NAME/NUMBER</describe35>
  <describe70>VESSEL-CONCEAL NAME/NUMBER</describe70>      
  <description>did operate and use a [boat/vessel] on the navigable waters  Custom Service] was knowingly [concealed/covered/defaced].</description>      
</cjischarge>    
<cjischarge>
  <cjisid>1220</cjisid>
  <chargeid>5762</chargeid>
  <cjiscode>10000</cjiscode>
  <class>A</class>
  <cjisclass>1A0000</cjisclass>
  <describe35>ATT-VESSEL-CONCEAL NAME/NUMBER</describe35>
  <describe70>ATT-VESSEL-CONCEAL NAME/NUMBER</describe70>      
  <description>did attempt to operate and use a [boat/vessel] on the [concealed/covered/defaced].</description>      
</cjischarge>    
<cjischarge>
  <cjisid>1280</cjisid>
  <chargeid>5822</chargeid>
  <cjiscode>10000</cjiscode>
  <class>C</class>
  <cjisclass>1C0000</cjisclass>
  <describe35>CON-VESSEL-CONCEAL NAME/NUMBER</describe35>
  <describe70>CON-VESSEL-CONCEAL NAME/NUMBER</describe70>      
  <description>did conspire with ____ (name) to operate and use a [concealed/covered/defaced].</description>      
</cjischarge>    
<cjischarge>
  <cjisid>2</cjisid>
  <chargeid>2</chargeid>
  <cjiscode>10001</cjiscode>
  <class></class>
  <cjisclass>1 0001</cjisclass>
  <describe35>IMPERSONATING AN OFFICER</describe35>
  <describe70>IMPERSONATING AN OFFICER</describe70>      
  <description></description>      
</cjischarge>
</cjischarges>
```

I am trying to parse the nodes - to show only where the "description" node is not empty.

I've tried the following, but still get empty "description" fields.

```
try {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    InputStream istream = new FileInputStream(folder + xmlFileName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Parse File: " + folder + xmlFileName);
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(istream);
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("cjischarge");
    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        if (nList.item(0).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
            Element elm = (Element) nList.item(i);
            // previously: if (!getNodeValue("description", elm).isEmpty()); {
            if (!getNodeValue("description", elm).isEmpty())
                ;
            {
                user.put("cjisclass", getNodeValue("cjisclass", elm) + " - "
                            + getNodeValue("describe70", elm));
                // user.put("describe70", getNodeValue("describe70",elm));
                user.put("description", getNodeValue("description", elm));
                userList.add(user);
            }
        }
    }
} // ...
```

Please advise suggestions to remove nodes where "description" fields are empty.

Comment: `if(!getNodeValue("description", elm).isEmpty()); {` ← Remove the `;`.

Comment: @VGR good catch, this is why strong formatting is important. Your IDEs have formatters, make use of them!

Comment: wow, missed that - thank you!! A studio didn't mark as error or issue?? weird. Works great, now!